# MS Word 2010: STYLEREF in page headers not displaying on all pages

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, headers

I have a ~30 page MS Word 2010 document with a number of Heading 1 titles and tables in-between.

In the page header I have inserted a STYLEREF referencing the Heading 1 style (double-click a header, goto Insert tab and choose Quick Parts > Field).

On most pages this works fine, and the heading text is displayed correctly in the page header. However, **in one section, on some consecutive pages the text suddenly stops appearing in the page header**.

If I toggle field codes (http://mikefrobbins.com/2010/05/10/how-to-toggle-field-codes-off-or-on-in-word/), I can see that the codes are indeed present on the pages where the heading text isn't displayed in the page headers.

Also, there seems to be no empty Heading 1 on the pages where the heading text isn't displayed or no section break, which perhaps(?) breaks the references?

- **What might be preventing the heading text from appearing in the page header?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.** In one of the table cells (in the section where some of the headings weren't displayed in the page header) there was a picture wrapped in a Heading 1 style. I found out when I created a TOC and the picture appeared in it.